# Does Anyone know which filter is this? Its used by a illustrator called Ilya Kuvshinov

Tags: effect, reverse-engineering

This filter is used by the illustrator Ilya Kuvshinov, it has a little bit of chromatic aberration which is not too noticeable on the picture.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Photo Stack Exchange. Please see [this thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/677/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-how-do-i-achieve-this-effect-question) in regards to asking questions like this.

Comment: [GDSE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) could be a better place to ask this kind of questions.

Comment: What makes you say that the chromatic aberration is added by a filter? This just looks like a highly-saturated phone camera shot to me. Can you describe specifically the aspects you'd like to replicate?

Comment: I want to replicate the over saturation and the chromatic aberration, the shot was taken by a iphone X, i own the same phone and tried a lot of filters, but couldnt get the same results, i suspect that it is a paid filter,  you can notice the chromatic aberration/rgb on the top right corner,right on the leaves.

Comment: It seems like you know more about this photograph than you write about in the question. Providing all the details you know will help people help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might a canned effect, but someone who is a skilled illustrator can probably do this to any iPhone photo with general purpose photo software (Photoshop, Gimp) without much effort at all, if that's what they want to achieve.

To me, this looks like the results from a low budget phone camera, and if it is an intentional effect from a camera which can do more, well, okay. The two easiest ways to do this are 1) learn the basics of photo editing software or 2) buy an old flip-phone and make it authentic. It's possible there's someone selling some app which applies post-processing to create this "look", but it's not necessary, either.